# How to embed PDF in chrome without error or warning

Tags: html, http, google-chrome, pdf, http-headers

I'm building an interface to view a long list of PDF documents (in Chrome) which are all `<embed>`s.

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="http://example.com/path/to/pdf/11749" type="application/pdf">
```

It works fine, but the console fills up with this (one for each embedded PDF):

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "http://example.com/path/to/pdf/11749".
```

I've seen this question asked before but never answered adequately. I don't want to install browser plugins or force downloads.

Comment: That's not an error its a warning.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/.

It's not only browser plugin. Check the examples. The implementation is rather simple